# Pycharm выдаёт ошибку

Tags: pycharm

Невозможно загрузить файл `C:\Users\Нургиса\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1`

так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений.

```
см. about_Execution_Policies по адресу https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: ну ок..........

Comment: запускаете\создаете проект с виртуальным пространством?

Answer (score 0):

1. Откройте PowerShell от имени администратора.
2. Введите команду: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.
3. Перезагрузите PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

переустанови PyCharm сработает)))

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).